# Back up only actual files in directory structure

Tags: backup, symlink

I want to backup my savegames:

```
+ /Library/Containers/com.doublefine.dfaosx/***
+ /Library/Containers/com.doublefine.dottosx/***
```

I initially wanted to do this as part of a larger `rsync` backup. However, because of some macOS sandbox insanity, the folders include dozens of symlinks that I don't want to backup up, and excluding these has proven difficult with `rsync` (see [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446440/exclude-symbolic-links-from-rsync-without-excessive-notification)).

How can I backup only the valuable savegame files and exclude the symlinks, without explicitly specifying a lot of subfolders. I want to specify "Back up all *real* files under this root folder, excluding symlinks and subfolders that don't ultimately contain a real file".

I tried `zip` also, but it doesn't even seem to have an option to exclude symlinks. Can `tar` do it? It would be best if `rsync` can do it, but if not, any standard Unix tool would be acceptable.

The files I want to backup are as below. Of course I could specify them explicitly, but I want to learn a way to backup *real files* and ignore symbolic links without getting specific about it.

```
Library/Containers/com.doublefine.dfaosx/Container.plist
Library/Containers/com.doublefine.dfaosx/Data/Documents/BrokenAge/saves/*
Library/Containers/com.doublefine.dfaosx/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.doublefine.dfaosx.savedState/*
```

The files in `saves` are called `auto.sav`, `auto.cav`, `slot_1.sav`, `slot_2.sav` and then some.

Example of symbolic links are (there are about 60 of these, most of which are irrelevant for the game, they are just created by default as a means of reaching some `Library` files):

```
Library/Containers/com.doublefine.dfaosx/Data/Library/ColorPickers
```

Comment: Do these "game files" have the same name?

Comment: Are the targets of the symlinks within the folders you want to backup or outside? In both cases how would you restore from backup if you don't include the symlinks? Also, do you know the names of the files you actually *want* to backup (and do these names stay stable)?

Comment: @nohillside: The symlinks are not used by the game. The names are numbered, but stay stable.

Comment: Are you sure that `Library/Containers/com.doublefine.dfaosx/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.doublefine.dfaosx.savedState/` doesn't contain a symlink in-between?

Comment: @nohillside: Real directories all the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of file names to backup to `tar` by running `find` first:

```
cd ~/Library/Containers/
tar -T <(find com.doublefine.dfaosx -type f -print) -cvzf ~/dfaosx.tar.gz
tar -T <(find com.doublefine.dottosx -type f -print) -cvzf ~/dfaosx.tar.gz
```

If you prefer `rsync` it supports a `--files-from` option which more or less does the same as `-T` for `tar`.

Comment: Not bad! An acceptable alternative if I can't make it work with the main `rsync` backup.